# setWindowFilePath didn't work in Qt at all

Tags: c++, qt, title, titlebar

Why setWindowFilePath didn't work? Slot is working. The window title does not change.
My OS is Windows 7, Qt was compiled with wchar_t support.

```
test::test(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
  ui.setupUi(this);
  QObject::connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(Click()));
  setWindowTitle("Title");
}

void test::Click()
{
  setWindowFilePath("file.txt");
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have the same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493965/how-to-use-qt-setwindowfilepath

Comment: No, if I use QTimer, like there, it did'n work too.

Comment: And QMetaObject::invokeMethod didn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your problem is that you already used `setWindowTitle()` before using `setWindowFilePath()`. From the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#windowFilePath-prop):

> If the window title is set at any point, then the window title takes precedence and will be shown instead of the file path string.

**Edit:** I just tried using `setWindowFilePath()` and noticed that it only takes effect if you call it *after* you call `show()`. Since this isn't mentioned in the docs, it smells like a bug...

**Edit:** Well, if it doesn't work without using `setWindowTitle()` or with calling `setWindowFilePath()` after calling `show()`, I don't know what your problem is. I've made a working example so I hope this helps you in tracking down your problem:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:

        MyWindow()
        {
            QPushButton* b = new QPushButton("Click me", this);
            connect(b, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(click()));
        }

    private Q_SLOTS:

        void click()
        {
            setWindowFilePath("file.txt");
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyWindow w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```